# Column 'class_id' cannot be null

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem in the student promotion features on my dashboar, and I'm very dizzy yet to find a solution to overcome Notifications:

> Error Number: 1048 Column 'class_id' can not be null INSERT INTO
>   `enroll` (`enroll_code`, `student_id`,`class_id`, `year`,
>   `date_added`) VALUES ('a18b241', '254', NULL, '2019-2020', 1532682443)
>
> Filename: C: /xampp/htdocs/sisnef/application/controllers/Admin.php
>
> Line Number: 860

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {
        if($.isFunction($.fn.selectBoxIt))
  {
   $("select.selectboxit").each(function(i, el)
   {
    var $this = $(el),
     opts = {
      showFirstOption: attrDefault($this, 'first-option', true),
      'native': attrDefault($this, 'native', false),
      defaultText: attrDefault($this, 'text', ''),
     };
     
    $this.addClass('visible');
    $this.selectBoxIt(opts);
   });
  }
    });
</script>
```

```html
   <?php 
    $students = $this->db->get_where('enroll' , array(
     'class_id' => $class_id_from , 'year' => $running_year
    ))->result_array();
    foreach($students as $row):
     $query = $this->db->get_where('enroll' , array(
      'student_id' => $row['student_id'],
       'year' => $promotion_year
      ));
   ?>
    <tr>
     
     <td align="center">
      <?php echo $this->db->get_where('student' , array('student_id' => $row['student_id']))->row()->name;?>
     </td>
     <td align="center">
      <?php if($row['section_id'] != '' && $row['section_id'] != 0)
        echo $this->db->get_where('section' , array('section_id' => $row['section_id']))->row()->name;
      ?>
     </td>
     <td align="center"><?php echo $row['roll'];?></td>
     <td>
      <?php if($query->num_rows() < 1):?>
       <select class="form-control selectboxit" name="promotion_status_<?php echo $row['student_id'];?>" id="promotion_status">
        <option value="<?php echo $class_id_to;?>">
         <?php echo get_phrase('Promotion-to') ." - ". $this->crud_model->get_class_name($class_id_to);?>
        </option>
        <option value="<?php echo $class_id_from;?>">
         <?php echo get_phrase('Promotion-to') ." - ". $this->crud_model->get_class_name($class_id_from);?>
       </select>
      <?php endif;?>
      <?php if($query->num_rows() > 0):?>
       <center>
       <button class="btn btn-success">
        <i class="entypo-check"></i> <?php echo get_phrase('Already');?>
       </button>
       </center>
      <?php endif;?>
     </td>
    </tr>
   <?php endforeach;?>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
 <center>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
   <i class="fa fa-check"></i> <?php echo get_phrase('Promotion-Selected');?>
  </button>
 </center>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

I really hope to get a good solution for this case. thank you

Comment: That's a PHP/MySQL question, not JavaScript.

Comment: Column 'class_id' can not be null, the problem is in the **INSERT** query, check values before INSERT. And if class_id can be null just declare it NULL in the table structure

Comment: I forgot to call. this link mysql php screenshot and its function

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mFNH8TsdCjhUaFxGcgTw1dnHYyDl6ote/view?usp=sharing https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UU_Sp4mANTWlkh3l7m8f7hYZvtP7C5VU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mFNH8TsdCjhUaFxGcgTw1dnHYyDl6ote/view

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mFNH8TsdCjhUaFxGcgTw1dnHYyDl6ote/view

Comment: Please don't post stuff in the comments, edit your question and paste code there, thanks.

Comment: @DanzMuhammad Check my Answer it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a value for `class_id`.

Where is `$class_id_from` defined? Make sure it has a value set.

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your Screenshot

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mFNH8TsdCjhUaFxGcgTw1dnHYyDl6ote/view

You have to do

```
`class_id` varchar(20) NULL,
```

class_id can be null just declare it NULL in the table structure

Check my Screenshot [image]

Comment: Are you sure `class_id` can be null? How would students enroll to a class then? And why make an `*_id` field `varchar` and not `int`

Comment: Mysql I have changed, the error problem is solved. Thank you sir. The main problem is that the student does not go to class (not saved to the database) which is still empty ..

Comment: Ok.. one more sir. how to make that student enter the database that is up the class. with the VARCHAR format, as I've tried to exploit the function (class_id) in my file controller. the results do not get error notification but the database remains empty and the result is the same. is there any other solution for the database to come in?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15u-e7Wld5deR18DR8aYlS9lPmNjyUWLc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @DanzMuhammad First accept this answer then i will help you.